Classification of geodesics in Lorentzian geometry
Consider the real vector space $\mathbb R^{2,2} = (\mathbb R^{4}, b)$ with the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form of signature $(2,2)$ $$b(x,y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2-x_3y_3-x_4y_4$$
Consider $AdS^3$ be the set $$AdS^3 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid b(x,x) = -1\}$$
I have proved that tangent space at $x \in AdS^3$, $T_x AdS^3 = x^\perp$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2,2} = \text{Span}\{x\} \oplus  \text{Span}\{x\}^{\perp}$. Let $g = b\Big|_{x^\perp}$. then $AdS^3$ endowed with $g $ is a $3$ dimensional Lorentzian manifold.
I want to find the geodesic of $AdS^3$.  I want to classify geodesics, i.e. timelike, lightlike and spacelike geodesics.
My attempt: Let $x \in AdS^3$ and $v \in T_x AdS^3$. i want to find geodesics $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma^\prime (0) = v$. $E$ be the subspace spanned by $\{x, v\}$.  Now consider restriction $b|_E$. The negative index of $AdS^3  \cap E$  would be either $1$ or $2$, otherwise the  intersection would be zero. Now I think there. would  be subcases, depending on $b\Big|_E$.
Case 1: $b\Big|_E$ is negative definite, i.e. $b\Big|_E$ has signature $(0,2)$.
Now I cannot proceed further.
Can anyone please help me?

Geodesics in the sphere are great circles: intersections of the sphere with planes passing through the origin.
Geodesics of ${\rm AdS}^3$ will be intersections of ${\rm AdS}^3$ with planes passing through the origin. What the intersection will be (hyperbola, circle, or line) depends on the causal type of $v\in x^\perp \smallsetminus \{0\}$.

If $v$ is spacelike, then $\gamma(t) =\cosh(t\|v\|)x+\sinh(t\|v\|)v/\|v\|$ has $\langle \gamma(t),\gamma(t)\rangle = -1$, so that $\gamma(t) \in {\rm AdS}^3$, with $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=v$. It is a geodesic because $\ddot{\gamma}(t) = \|v\|^2\gamma(t)$ is normal to ${\rm AdS}^3$.
If $v$ is timelike, then $\gamma(t) = \cos(t\|v\|)x + \sin(t\|v\|) v/\|v\|$ has $\langle \gamma(t),\gamma(t)\rangle = -1$, so that $\gamma(t) \in {\rm AdS}^3$, with $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=v$. It is a geodesic because $\ddot{\gamma}(t) = -\|v\|^2\gamma(t)$ is normal to ${\rm AdS}^3$.
If $v$ is lightlike, then $\gamma(t) = x+tv$ has $\langle \gamma(t),\gamma(t)\rangle = -1$, so that $\gamma(t) \in {\rm AdS}^3$, with $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=v$. It is a geodesic because $\ddot{\gamma}(t) = 0$ is normal to ${\rm AdS}^3$.

Geodesics are uniquely determined by their starting point and initial velocity. We have exhibited geodesics realizing all possible initial conditions. Hence these are all of them.
